# Sending arrayList index to a ajax function in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have the following list in my Jsp page.Each row in the list is accompanied by a button.
When I click om that button I need to pas the row index to the controller.

```
<tr th:each="idBean : ${idBeanLst}" >
                <td th:text="${idBeanStat.count}" id="count"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.identifierId}" id="idenId"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.idNumber}" id="idNumber"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.issueLocation}" id="issueLocation"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.issueDate}" id="issueDate"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.expiryDate}" id="expDt"></td>

                <td><button type="button" name="identifierRow" id="identifierRow" th:value="${idBeanStat.index}" onclick="doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(${idBean.index})">Remove</button>
                </td>
```

```
function doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(id) {
        alert(id);
            //do ajax call to the controller..
}
```

But I am not able to pass the row id .Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: Is it possible to send the index of the element which is selected to pass toa javascript funtion?

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
<button type="button" name="identifierRow" id="identifierRow" th:value="${idBeanStat.index}" th:onclick="'javascript:doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(\'' + ${idBeanStat.index} + '\');'">Remove</button>
```

Thanks to @ohiocowboy for suggesting me to use th:onclick.Hope this helps some one else.

Answer (score 0):

See 6.2 of the docs. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html

`${idBean.index}` will get you the index

Comment: I tried to do the following <button type="button" name="identifierRow" id="identifierRow" th:value="${idBeanStat.index}" onclick="doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(${idBeanStat.index})">Remove</button> but it is not working

Comment: That's because variable idBeanStat doesn't exist, but variable idBean does. use idBean.index in place of idBeanStat.index

Comment: No It is not working Cant understand the problem Here is what I did     <button type="button" name="identifierRow" id="identifierRow" th:value="${idBeanStat.index}" onclick="doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(${idBean.index})">Remove</button>

Comment: @AyanBiswas you need to use th:onclick

Comment: this is what worked for me th:onclick="'javascript:doAjaxCallRemoveIdentifier(\'' + ${idBeanStat.index} + '\');'"